# What do these "Failed to import" errors mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: errors, import

Do I need to fix it if the web page displays correctly? Please advise.

The demo import has finished. Please check your front page and make sure that everything has imported correctly. If it did, you can deactivate the FameThemes Demo Importer plugin, because it has done its job.

Failed to import pa_color Black: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import pa_color Blue: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_type external: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import pa_color Green: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_type grouped: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_type simple: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_type variable: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Clothing: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Hoodies: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Music: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Posters: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Singles: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat T-shirts: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import product_cat Albums: Invalid taxonomy.
Failed to import “Woo Logo”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Patient Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Happy Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Ninja Silhouette”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Logo”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Flying Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Premium Quality”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Logo”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Album #1”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Album #2”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Album #3”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Single #1”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Premium Quality”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Ninja Silhouette”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Happy Ninja”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Frontpage contact”: Invalid post type wpcf7_contact_form
Failed to import “Variation #41 of Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product_variation
Failed to import “Variation #42 of Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product_variation
Failed to import “Woo Album #4”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Woo Single #2”: Invalid post type product
Failed to import “Variation #23 of Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product_variation
Failed to import “Variation #24 of Ship Your Idea”: Invalid post type product_variation
Failed to import “Order – April 9, 2016 @ 01:40 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – April 20, 2016 @ 03:44 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – April 20, 2016 @ 03:00 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – June 7, 2016 @ 08:32 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – June 25, 2016 @ 07:21 AM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – June 26, 2016 @ 05:00 AM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – July 12, 2016 @ 09:04 AM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – July 17, 2016 @ 08:16 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – August 4, 2016 @ 03:13 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – August 13, 2016 @ 05:54 AM”: Invalid post type shop_order
Failed to import “Order – October 2, 2016 @ 05:03 PM”: Invalid post type shop_order

Comment: It looks like it's trying to import Woocommerce data, do you have the Woocommerce plugin installed and activated?

Comment: No I don't. Should I?

Comment: I suppose there's no harm if you don't plan on using it. It's just test data anyway.

Comment: If I do plan on using it, how should I fix this?

Comment: it's just dummy data used for testing or theme demo, you can add Woocommerce later without it and all will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) plugin on your site. Before, importing the XML file.